# How to Install Pentaho as service on window?

Tags: java, tomcat, pentaho

I want to Install pentaho as service.

**Following are the onfiguration that I have done** ::

```
ENVIRONMENT VARIABLES:

VARIABLE_NAME :- JAVA_OPTS
VARIABLE_VALUE :- -Xmx1024m -Xms256m

VARIABLE_NAME :- PENTAHO_CATALINA_HOME
VARIABLE_VALUE :- E:\Softwares\biserver-ce-4.8.0-stable\biserver-ce\tomcat

VARIABLE_NAME :- JAVA_HOME
VARIABLE_VALUE :-

VARIABLE_NAME :- CATALINA_OPTS
VARIABLE_VALUE :- -Xms256m -Xmx768m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=3600000 -Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=3600000
```

For Creating Pentaho service

```
Step 1) `cd  E:\pentaho\pentaho 4.5\biserver-ce-4.5.0-stable\biserver-ce\tomcat\bin`

Step 2) 
Command :- 
service install Pentaho
```

but it gives error.

[image: error]

Answer (score 1):

Check out this link, this explains all the things how to install pentaho 4.5 CE as service.
 [how to install pentaho 4.5 CE as service](http://tunwinnaing.wordpress.com/2012/12/01/pentaho-service-on-windows-64-bit/)

Answer (score 0):

You given Pentaho 4.5.0 stable at the time of setting variables and in screen-shot it is displaying `biserver-ce-4.8.0 stable`..

so may be because of this mis-match you are getting error.

After downloading biserver 4.8 you have to extract the file and you have to run start-pentaho batch file from bi-server folder..

Do this things only then type `localhost:8080`, your bi-server will be running.

no need to do all this things which you are doing.
hope it will work.

Comment: by mistake it is typed here.but i have used biserver-ce-4.8.0 in envt. variable so no issue.

Comment: thanx but i know about start-pentaho batch.but I have to keep running this batch file even i logoff from machine.for this i need creation of service.

Comment: you opened cmd with administrator permissions or normal cmd only?

Comment: opened normal cmd only

Comment: try with administrator permissions.

Comment: I have tried it,still facing the same problem.i am using JAVA_HOME = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0\jre"  is it correct??

Comment: you have to add two different path 1 for JDK and 1 for JRE,
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0\
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6

 i shared 1 reference document you can follow and try the same..